# How to retrieve the @value from message?

Tags: logstash

i want to retrieve the value from snmptrap input ,

The following log was generated while creating a loop,.

```
{
   "message" => "#@enterprise=[1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.187],@timestamp=#@value=2612151602>, @varbind_list=[#@name=  [1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.187.1.2.5.1.17.32.1.14.16.255.255.17.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.2], @value=\"\x00\x00\">, #@name=[1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.187.1.2.5.1.3.32.1.14.16.255.255.17.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.2], @value=#@value=1>>, #@name=[1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.187.1.2.5.1.28.32.1.14.16.255.255.17.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.2], @value=\"\">, #@name=[1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.187.1.2.5.1.29.32.1.14.16.255.255.17.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.2], @value=#@value=3>>], @specific_trap=7, @source_ip=\"1.2.3.4\", @agent_addr=#@value=\"\xC0\xA8\v\e\">, @generic_trap=6>"
}
```

i want to retrive the value @source_ip from message , i try to use

```
mutate {
   add_field => { "source_ip" =>["@source_ip"] } 
   }
```

to get the @souce_ip and for the new field , but still can't get the value ,
If anyone knows how to do with it , please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "@source_ip" information is not a field in what you've shown, but rather part of the [message] field.  I would guess that the snmptrap{} input is not entirely happy with the message.

Given the example you have, you could run the message through the grok{} filter to pull out the "@source_ip" information.

I stopped using the snmptrap{} input due to other processing issues. I now run snmptrapd and have it write a json log file that is then read by a simple file{} input in logstash.